# qBittorent, FileBot, mkvmerge - remux all video files to *.mkv and remove subtitles in process

Tags: batch-file, command-line, cmd, mkv

I am trying to execute this very useful batch for processing all *.avi, *.mkv and *.mp4 files in current directory and all subdirectories and producing *.mkv files (removing subtitles in the process) with deletion of original file

```
@echo off
for /F "delims=" %%I in ('dir /A-D /B /ON /S *.avi *.mkv *.mp4 2^>nul') do (
    mkvmerge.exe "%%~I" -o "%%~dpI~%%~nI.tmp" --no-subtitles
    if not errorlevel 1 (
        del "%%~I"
        move /Y "%%~dpI~%%~nI.tmp" "%%~dpnI.mkv" >nul
    )
)
```

with Filebots [AMC](https://www.filebot.net/forums/viewtopic.php?f=4&t=215) script (qBittorrent)

```
filebot -script fn:amc --output "/path/to/media" --action duplicate --conflict skip -non-strict --log-file amc.log --def excludeList=amc.excludes unsorted=y music=y artwork=y "ut_dir=%F" "ut_kind=multi" "ut_title=%N" "ut_label=%L"
```

in combination with its [--def exec=command](https://www.filebot.net/forums/viewtopic.php?f=4&t=5047)

```
--def exec="mkvpropedit {quote f} --edit info --set title={quote object}"
```

So I tried to adapt the batch to qBittorrents variable and called it filebot.bat:

```
mkvmerge.exe "%F" -o "%F.tmp" --no-subtitles
if not errorlevel 1 (
    del "%F"
    move /Y "%F.tmp" "%F.mkv" >nul
)
```

and adjusted the AMC script accordingly

```
filebot -script fn:amc --output "D:\Desktop\filebot\test2" --action duplicate --conflict skip -non-strict --log-file amc.log --def excludeList=amc.excludes unsorted=n music=y artwork=n "ut_dir=D:\Desktop\filebot\test1\test.avi" "ut_kind=multi" --def exec="D:\Desktop\filebot\test3\filebot.bat {quote f}"
```

AMC works just like it should but when the --def exec command gets triggered this happens:

```
C:\Users\Admin>mkvmerge.exe "F.tmp" --no-subtitles
mkvmerge v13.0.0 ('The Juggler') 64bit
Error: no destination file name was given.

mkvmerge -o out [global options] [options1] <file1> [@option-file.json] …
```

I guess it has something to do with the qBittorrent variable "%F". 
I would really really appreciate some help!

Edit: I deleted everything else inside the batch and adjusted it to

```
mkvmerge.exe "%~1" -o "%~dpn1.tmp" --no-subtitles && >NUL move /Y "%~dpn1.tmp" "%~n1.mkv"
```

This is what cmd says after AMC already worked properly:

```
C:\Users\Admin>mkvmerge.exe "D:\Desktop\filebot\test2\TV Shows\StartUp (2016)\Season 01\StartUp (2016) - S01E01 - Seed Money.avi" -o "D:\Desktop\filebot\test2\TV Shows\StartUp (2016)\Season 01\StartUp (2016) - S01E01 - Seed Money.tmp" --no-subtitles   && move /Y "D:\Desktop\filebot\test2\TV Shows\StartUp (2016)\Season 01\StartUp (2016) - S01E01 - Seed Money.tmp" "StartUp (2016) - S01E01 - Seed Money.mkv" 1>NUL
mkvmerge v13.0.0 ('The Juggler') 64bit
'D:\Desktop\filebot\test2\TV Shows\StartUp (2016)\Season 01\StartUp (2016) - S01E01 - Seed Money.avi': Using the demultiplexer for the format 'Matroska'.
'D:\Desktop\filebot\test2\TV Shows\StartUp (2016)\Season 01\StartUp (2016) - S01E01 - Seed Money.avi' track 0: Using the output module for the format 'AVC/h.264'.
'D:\Desktop\filebot\test2\TV Shows\StartUp (2016)\Season 01\StartUp (2016) - S01E01 - Seed Money.avi' track 1: Using the output module for the format 'AAC'.
'D:\Desktop\filebot\test2\TV Shows\StartUp (2016)\Season 01\StartUp (2016) - S01E01 - Seed Money.avi' track 2: Using the output module for the format 'text subtitles'.
'D:\Desktop\filebot\test2\TV Shows\StartUp (2016)\Season 01\StartUp (2016) - S01E01 - Seed Money.avi' track 3: Using the output module for the format 'text subtitles'.
The file 'D:\Desktop\filebot\test2\TV Shows\StartUp (2016)\Season 01\StartUp (2016) - S01E01 - Seed Money.tmp' has been opened for writing.
Progress: 100%
The cue entries (the index) are being written...
Multiplexing took 6 seconds.
Done ?(?????)?
```

The file is still .avi and has still subtitles.

Answer (score 2):

The AMC script triggers the .bat script with `--def exec="path\to\filebot.bat {quote f}"` right?  I think the problem is that within `filebot.bat`, the command-line argument should be read as `"%~1"`, not `%F`.

```js
mkvmerge.exe -S "%~1" -o "%~dpn1.tmp" && >NUL move /Y "%~dpn1.tmp" "%~dpn1.mkv"
```

ought to do it I think.  By the way, `&&` takes the place of `if not errorlevel 1`.  `%~dpn1` means drive, path, basename of argument 1.

Comment: Add a `pause` at the end so you can examine the output of `mkvmerge`.  If nothing else, do you have ffmpeg?  You could try `ffmpeg -i "%~1" -map 0:v -map -0:a -c:v copy -c:a copy "%~dpn1.mkv"` as an alternative.

Comment: @Liche1992 It'll remux with whatever streams you specify.  As long as you only specify the video and audio streams, those are the streams it will remux -- along with their associated metadata, as well as the global container's metadata (title, chapter list, etc).  The command I commented above will create a new Matroska file containing the most significant video and audio stream from the old file.  If your original file has multiple audio streams, it'll only copy the one with the most channels or highest bitrate.  If multiple streams meet that condition, it copies the first occurring.

Comment: @Liche1992 You could edit your question and add what you've tried, and the resulting log results.  If the relevant log information is inappropriately long, you could post a link to a pastebin paste.

Comment: @Liche1992 Sorry, I added an extra dash character between `0:a`.  Should be `ffmpeg -i "%~1" -map 0:v -map 0:a -c:v copy -c:a copy "%~dpn1.mkv"`

Comment: @Liche1992 According to the [mkvmerge documentation](https://mkvtoolnix.download/doc/mkvmerge.html#mkvmerge.option_order), the order of options is important.  `-S` or `--no-subtitles` must come *before* the input filename.  I edited my answer to reflect that.

Comment: @Liche1992 Surround code with backticks in StackOverflow comments.  And you know what?  I think I just realized my mistake.  Change that to `move /Y "%~dpn1.tmp" "%~dpn1.mkv"`.  I think I had the `ren` command syntax on my brain.  `move` needs the fully qualified path as the destination -- otherwise, files end up in the current working directory, which is probably not the directory containing the video.  Sorry about that!

Comment: @Liche1992 Oh sorry, I had a response typed out then backspaced it after I saw my mistake.  Anyway, `mkvmerge` will more reliably give you the results you want if you can get it to work I think, especially on videos with unpredictable stream configurations (such as multilingual videos).  `ffmpeg` could decide the Portuguese audio track is the most significant track, and will only copy that one without some intense acrobatics with the `-map` switches.